# Pandas histogram (counts) on grouped (by) values

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, histogram

I have a `DataFrame` which looks like this:

```
>>> df
    type     value
0      1  0.698791
1      3  0.228529
2      3  0.560907
3      1  0.982690
4      1  0.997881
5      1  0.301664
6      1  0.877495
7      2  0.561545
8      1  0.167920
9      1  0.928918
10     2  0.212339
11     2  0.092313
12     4  0.039266
13     2  0.998929
14     4  0.476712
15     4  0.631202
16     1  0.918277
17     3  0.509352
18     1  0.769203
19     3  0.994378
```

I would like to group on the `type` column and obtain histogram bins for the column `value` in 10 new columns, e.g. something like that:

```
      1  3  9  6  8  10  5  4  7  2
type
1     0  1  0  0  0   2  1  1  0  1
2     2  1  1  0  0   1  1  0  0  0
3     2  0  0  0  0   1  1  0  0  0
4     1  1  0  0  0   1  0  0  0  1
```

Where column `1` is the count for the first bin (`0.0` to `0.1`) and so on...

Using `numpy.histogram`, I can only obtain the following:

```
>>> df.groupby('type')['value'].agg(lambda x: numpy.histogram(x, bins=10, range=(0, 1)))
    type
1       ([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2], [0.0, 0.1, 0....
2       ([2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [0.0, 0.1, 0....
3       ([2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0.0, 0.1, 0....
4       ([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0.0, 0.1, 0....
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Which I do not manage to put in the correct format afterwards (at least not in a simple way).

I found a trick to do what I want, but it is very ugly:

```
>>> d = {str(k): lambda x, _k = k: ((x >= (_k - 1)/10) & (x < _k/10)).sum() for k in range(1, 11)}
>>> df.groupby('type')['value'].agg(d)
      1  3  9  6  8  10  5  4  7  2
type
1     0  1  0  0  0   2  1  1  0  1
2     2  1  1  0  0   1  1  0  0  0
3     2  0  0  0  0   1  1  0  0  0
4     1  1  0  0  0   1  0  0  0  1
```

Is there a better way to do what I want? I know that in `R`, the `aggregate` method can return a `DataFrame`, but not in python...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [98]: %paste
bins = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 11)
labels = list(range(1,11))

(df.assign(q=pd.cut(df.value, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False))
   .pivot_table(index='type', columns='q', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[98]:
q     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
type
1      0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   4
2      1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
3      0   0   1   0   0   2   0   0   0   1
4      1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: It may do the trick - I do not have `DataFrame.assign`, I will see if I can update my `pandas` version (I may not be able to... ). Is it possible to use this if I want to group on two columns, e.g. `type` and `version`?

Comment: @Holt, i used `.assign()` to make it an one-liner, you can add this column first and then use it as a second command. For the `version` - i think you should update your sample and expected DFs in the question, because it's not quite clear

Comment: I managed to get it working by using `df['bin'] = pd.cut(...)`. I was worried that `.pivot_table` may not work with two indexes but it does (`index=('col1', 'col2')`), and that I would have to drop a lot of columns (my real dataframe has a lot of columns) but apparently the `drop` is not necessary to get it working. I also add to add an extra bins from `1.0` to `1.1` to get a specific bin when `value == 1` (but I forgot this in my question so you could not guess... ). Thanks.

Comment: Also a small detail: In order to correctly mimic `numpy.histogram`, the  `right` parameter should be set to `False` in the call to `pandas.cut` (by default `numpy.histogram` bins are left-inclusive (`[a, b)`) while `pandas.cut` bins are right-inclusive (`(a, b]`) by default).

Comment: @Holt, another good point, thank you! :) I've updated the answer